# Accesing UFT scripts from SVN repository by Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, tortoisesvn, hp-uft

I've been using SVN Repository for UFT Scripts. I tried to integrate SVN and Jenkins and run the UFT scripts directly from the SVN Repository without checking out the SVN repository. But I did not find a way through for doing it.

Can anyone please suggest on this problem?

Comment: If your scripts are in the repository, then why wouldn't you just check them out to the test execution machine before running them? What is the goal/benefit you are trying to achieve?

Comment: I do not want to checkout the repository manually into the test execution machine, I want Jenkins to directly pick the scripts from the SVN repository or checkout the SVN repository into test execution machine by Jenkins itself. 
My Goal is to avoid manual intervention(for the checkout to the test execution machine) and I want Jenkins to do it using any plugins if available

Comment: You can configure Jenkins to execute the svn update/checkout command as a prerequisite to running the UFT scripts.  Look at https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Subversion+Plugin for some more details